# Filtering / reindexing in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have the following problem in Python Pandas:

final_list:

| date | test3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2001-11-01 | NaT |
| 2001-11-02 | NaT |
| 2001-11-02 | 2001-11-02 |
| 2001-11-05 | 2001-11-05 |

```
df_daily_strategy[~df_daily_strategy.index.isin(final_list.test3)]
```

I want that df_daily_strategy shows values where I have in final_list.test3 'NaT' values. With my code unfortunately it hides all values in df_daily_strategy where the index matches with the date in final_list.test3.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say much about df_daily_strategy but I'm assuming it has a datetime index and you are trying to identify those dates with NaT values from final_list. You could try something like the following:

```
# get the date column values where test3 is NaT
dates = final_list.loc[final_list.test3.isna(), 'date']

# use the date column values to index df_daily_strategy
df_daily_strategy.loc[dates, :]
```

Comment: would you know how I can get instead of the loc position, the iloc position? cause I have multiple items in df_daily_strategy with the same date

Comment: You need to post sample contents of df_daily_strategy to answer this.

Comment: I managed to solve it by adding a column which serves as series that can be given to iloc. Thank you for the help though! You're idea with loc really helped.